How make this Complex table structure?
I can’t visualize, how make this table ?

Is anyone know about this ?

Could you show us how far you got yourself? Can you for example do the table without the lines? I'm sure people would then be able to help you with the rest.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can use \hhline in order to get well connected rules at the angles.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,hhline}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\RR}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c cccc c @{}}
 & $D_1$ & $D_2$ & $D_3$ & $D_4$ & Supply \\
\hhline{~|----|~}
\RR{$S_1$} & 6 & 8 & 8 & \RR{5} & 30 \\
\RR{$S_2$} & 5 & 11 & 9 & \RR{7} & 40 \\
\RR{$S_3$} & 8 & 9 & 7 & \RR{13} & 50 \\
\hhline{~|----|-}
Demand & 35 & 28 & 32 & \RR{25} & \RR{120} \\
\hhline{~~~~~|-}
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}

I locally define a shorthand for the cells where a vertical rule has to be added.

A different way to typeset the table.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{@{} c cccc c @{}}
\toprule
 & $D_1$ & $D_2$ & $D_3$ & $D_4$ & Supply \\
\midrule
$S_1$ & 6 &  8 & 8 &  5 & 30 \\
$S_2$ & 5 & 11 & 9 &  7 & 40 \\
$S_3$ & 8 &  9 & 7 & 13 & 50 \\
\midrule
Demand & 35 & 28 & 32 & 25 & \textbf{120} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}



Since you put tabularray among your tags:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={*6c},
    hline{2-X}={2-Y}{},
    hline{Y}={2-Z}{},
    hline{Z}={Z}{},
    vline{2}={2-Y}{},
    vline{Y}={2-Z}{},
    vline{Z}={Z}{}
    }
     & $D_1$ & $D_2$ & $D_3$ & $D_4$ & Supply \\
    $S_1$ & 6 &  8 & 8 &  5 & 30 \\
    $S_2$ & 5 & 11 & 9 &  7 & 40 \\
    $S_3$ & 8 &  9 & 7 & 13 & 50 \\
    Demand & 35 & 28 & 32 & 25 & 120 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



thnx !, I am beginner in Latex field, so face problem in some table. Now can u guide me how fixed columns width(only for column 2,3,4,5 not for all column ) in this table ?

@DESHu Please ask a new question specifying which is your problem exactly (and adding a minimal example). Thank you.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}
 & $D_1$ & $D_2$ & $D_3$ & $D_4$ & Supply \\
$S_1$ & \Block[draw]{3-4}{} 6 &  8 & 8 &  5 & 30 \\
\cline{2-5}
$S_2$ & 5 & 11 & 9 &  7 & 40 \\
\cline{2-5}
$S_3$ & 8 &  9 & 7 & 13 & 50 \\
Demand & 35 & 28 & 32 & 25 & \Block[draw]{}{120} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}



However, I recommend a design in the spirit of booktabs (see egreg's answer).
